# How to get entered text after clicking a button and updating the variable out of the class?

Tags: python, class, tkinter, class-variables

I have a class written by tkinter for gui and want to do some work with the entered text after clicking a button,to do so I defined the command like this

```
def passVal(self):

    self.gotten_Value=self.tx.get()
```

Where `gotten_Value` is the value I defined earlier in the class with the initial value of "initial".
Now out of the class(that's what I want) when I define an object and call my `gotten_Value` it doesn't give me the entered text and keep showing "initial"after clicking.

```
import tkinter as tk
```

class Sui(tk.Tk):

```
gotten_Value="initial"

 

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.tx = tk.Entry(self)
    self.get_btn = tk.Button(self, text="get",command=self.passVal)
    self.tx.pack()
    self.get_btn.pack()
    
    
def passVal(self):
    self.gotten_Value=self.tx.get()
    

app = Sui()
print(app.gotten_Value)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: To me this sounds like you haven't bound the variable to the entry like: entry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.gotten_Value)  I would need to see more of the code where you instantiate the entry and gotten_Value to be sure.

Comment: Please provide a _complete_ [mcve]. Your description is too vague.

Comment: I added the code,I guess some loop is needed to keep updating the variable.